# Why can voltage error be converted to current using a PI controller in dq-frame?

Tags: matlab, controls, signal-processing, simulink, feedback

As shown in: [Voltage Control Block](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/5d8b5ef0-76d2-40f1-90e1-6ec5d8b1c32c/pel212293-fig-0002-m.jpg)

How could a PI controller convert the voltage error to current (in voltage control block)? or How could a PI controller convert the current error to voltage (in current control block)? *attached link for figure*
Take the voltage control of inverter as an example, where current control and voltage control are used. The voltage error, which comes from the load side (ABC to dq-frame), can be converted to a current reference using a PI controller. The current reference is used for the current control.
kindly, help me that how could a PI controller convert the current error to voltage (or voltage reference)? or explain that particular scenario.
Thanks in Advance

I'm working on controlling techniques of voltage of three-phase inverter, and I'm created the simulation. But for calculation purposes I can't find equations in d-q frame for current control block and voltage control block cause it helps me to generate PWM for inverter switching.
If you can help me to share equations or a paper that can help me then I'll be really thankful to you, kindly help me in this problem as I have to calculate the parameters to check out the results.
Thanks, once again!